# My Javascript File use another automatically, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, avaudioplayer, slick.js

i have the green-audio-player script and slick script. My green-audio-player doesn't work. If i delete my slick script, its work fine.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/audioPlayer/audioPlayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i use the audioPlayer in my index.html

```
<div class="player">
 <audio crossorigin>
  <source src="mp3/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
</div>
```

But i have a Problem after that. If i check the code in Google-Browser-Inspector
it seems automatically change the audio-player with slick-properties of slick.js File

```
<div class="volume__slider slider slick-initialized slick-slider slick- 
 dotted" data-direction="vertical" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="slick-list draggable"></div></div>
```

Can everyone explain me this magic?

Comment: Was the $.noConflict added before, or after, you started having problems.

Comment: after -> after the include my scripts

Comment: Why was it added? are you using two copies of jQuery.js?

Comment: no i dont use two Jquerys. But my script1 use variables of script2 and i would like to know why?

Comment: If you aren't using two copies of jquery, `$.noConflict` will cause more problems than it fixes, and has nothing to do with variables (other than `$` and `jQuery`) conflicting between scripts.

Comment: can i not set the prio1 or something else that my script1 not use srcipt2?

Comment: What is prio1?' You haven't really presented a problem for us to solve at this point.

Comment: sorry, It seems that slick.js does not work with audioplayer. If I remove the script everything works fine. However, I also need the script. According to the Chrome tool, variables are also used in the audio player. I would like to stop that

Comment: no idea @KevinB?

Comment: provide the information that would be needed to confirm any such conflict exists so we can do something

Answer (score -1):

Probably because JQuery is not loaded.

Be sure to add the JS file in html before your own script and to wait for it to be ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('html').addClass(isPoorBrowser ? 'poor-browser' : 'no-poor-browser');
});
```

[doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)